# How to handle enemies shooting in Phaser Js?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I’m making a top down shooter in PhaserJS for an university project. So, I have a tank in an arena and there are other enemy tanks. My problem is how to handle the enemies shooting, because I want they shoot only when they see me, that is only when their direction intersect the direction of the player. If you want I can post the code, but my question is if exists a function that does that or how I can do that? Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Game mechanics *(obstacle, enemies, ...)* and *when* the player should be seen or not, the solutions could range from:

- **basic:** just using the functions of the `Phaser.Geom.Intersects`
  namespace, like `LineToRectangle` or `LineToLine` ([documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Intersects.html#.LineToRectangle__anchor))
- **advanced:** some type of raycasting and than checking for intersection. The raycasting could be done with a phaser3 plugin https://github.com/wiserim/phaser-raycaster, there are a few example with this plugins on codepen. But [this one](https://codepen.io/wiserim/pen/GRJwJzE) in particular might be suitable for your problem *(if you want the advanced option)*.